# Drupal - Rules Email Tokens only include first of multiple CCK text field values

Tags: drupal

Im using Rules with email Tokens so when a node is created the entire node content including CCK text fields are sent in an email.

One of my CCK text fields has an unlimited number of values. However if more than 1 value is used, only the first value is included in the email. How can I include all values when their is more than 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token Array module fixes this problem: 
http://drupal.org/project/token_array